# vb.net how to Save excel Workbook to Specific Folder using Save Dialog Box

Tags: vb.net, excel

i want to save my datagridview into excel but i found code in some web is no use specific folder , i want to Save excel Workbook to Specific Folder using Save Dialog Box.

and this my code but this no save with specific folder.

```
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim misValue As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value

    Dim i As Int16, j As Int16

    'xlApp = New Excel.ApplicationClass
    xlApp = New Excel.Application()
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue)
    xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets("sheet1")

    For c As Integer = 0 To dgv1.Columns.Count - 1
        xlWorkSheet.Cells(1, c + 1).Value = dgv1.Columns(c).HeaderText
    Next

    For i = 0 To dgv1.RowCount - 2
        For j = 0 To dgv1.ColumnCount - 1
            xlWorkSheet.Cells(i + 2, j + 1) = dgv1(j, i).Value.ToString()
        Next
    Next

    xlWorkBook.SaveAs("d:\kehadiran.xls", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue,
     Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue)
    xlWorkBook.Close(True, misValue, misValue)
    xlApp.Quit()

    releaseObject(xlWorkSheet)
    releaseObject(xlWorkBook)
    releaseObject(xlApp)

    MessageBox.Show("Your File is successfully saved d:\kehadiran.xls")
```

Comment: you are getting an error ? which line ? you want to replace the `xlWorkBook.SaveAs("d:\kehadiran...` line with the SaveDialog Box ?

Comment: i want select some specifict folder like if u want save some file. like use this code but i want use for save  OpenFileDialog.InitialDirectory = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments
        OpenFileDialog.Filter = "All Files (*.*)|*.*|Excel files (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx|CSV Files (*.csv)|*.csv|XLS Files (*.xls)|*xls"

Comment: this is not VBA. I removed corresponding tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to let the user pick where they save the file, use the save file dialog. Right now, you're passing a hard-coded path to Workbook.SaveAs(). Use a SaveFileDialog to get a path, and replace the "d:\kehadiran.xls"'s with "savePath":

```
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim misValue As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value

    Dim i As Int16, j As Int16

    'xlApp = New Excel.ApplicationClass
    xlApp = New Excel.Application()
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue)
    xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets("sheet1")

    For c As Integer = 0 To dgv1.Columns.Count - 1
        xlWorkSheet.Cells(1, c + 1).Value = dgv1.Columns(c).HeaderText
    Next

    For i = 0 To dgv1.RowCount - 2
        For j = 0 To dgv1.ColumnCount - 1
            xlWorkSheet.Cells(i + 2, j + 1) = dgv1(j, i).Value.ToString()
        Next
    Next

    Dim savePath As String = Nothing
    Using sd As New SaveFileDialog
        With sd
            .RestoreDirectory = True
            .Filter = "Excel XLS Files(*.xls)|*.xls|Excel Macro Embedded Files(*.xlsm)|*.xlsm|Excel XLSX Files(*.xlsx)|*.xlsx"
            .FilterIndex = 3
            If .ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
                savePath = .FileName
            End If
        End With
    End Using

    If savePath IsNot Nothing AndAlso savePath.Trim <> "" Then
        xlWorkBook.SaveAs(savePath, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue)
    End If
    xlWorkBook.Close(True, misValue, misValue)
    xlApp.Quit()

    releaseObject(xlWorkSheet)
    releaseObject(xlWorkBook)
    releaseObject(xlApp)

    MessageBox.Show("Your File is successfully saved " & savePath)
```